# Search in a special technique Linq FrameWork

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

How do I search in variables only non-empty

```
Dim e = From Car_Company In Db.Car_Company _
        Where pID_Order_Buy = Nothing Or Car_Company.ID = pID_Order_Buy _
        Select _
        Car_Company.ID, _
        Car_Company.cName()
```

Error Line In:

```
Where pID_Order_Buy = Nothing Or CLng(Car_Company.ID) = pID_Order_Buy
```

In SQLSTRING =

```
SELECT * from car_company where (variable is null or id=variable )
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is
>   not valid.

Comment: Well what's the error?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: So what are all the types involved?

Comment: SELECT * from car_company where (varable is null or id=varable )

Comment: You still haven't told us the types involved - the types of the various properties and variables.

Comment: So is that the `Car_Company.ID` property? Why are you converting that to a `Long`? And what's the type of `pID_Order_Buy`?

Comment: sory ,,,         Where pID_Order_Buy = Nothing Or Car_Company.ID = pID_Order_Buy _